# What do you call those hats that only cover the top of your head?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I'm not really referring to the Jewish hats. More like this one (usually worn by Chinese, I think):

[image]

What's the name? I typed types of hats [on Google](https://www.google.com.tw/search?client=ubuntu&hs=qK7&biw=1357&bih=984&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=D34CXNf_LYOn8QXRnIiABA&q=types%20of%20hats&oq=types%20of%20hats&gs_l=img.3..35i39l2j0l8.75981.77104..77172...0.0..0.46.492.13......1....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i67.o6H_z438Qvg), but it doesn't show in the images.

Comment: I thought it was just referred to as a Chinese cap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s hard to tell for sure, because the picture you show is cartoonish. However, my first thought was to call it a *beanie cap*.

From a [Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-beanie-vs-skull-cap-vs-knit-hat):

> **What is the difference between beanie vs. skull cap vs. knit hat?**
>
> In parts of Canada and the United States, a **beanie** refers to a head-hugging brimless hat with or without a visor, usually seamed. Seamed beanies are made from triangular sections of cloth joined by a button at the crown, and seamed together around the sides. They can also be made from leather or silk panels.
>
> In other English-speaking countries and parts of the US and Canada, a "beanie" is a knitted cap (often woollen), known in parts of the United States as a "stocking cap" or "beanie" and in Canada as a "touques".
>
> Of course Google will show you only images of brimless, head hugging knitted caps. As noted, beanies are usually, though not always, seamed. In the past, the hat most commonly referred to as a beanie looked something like this:
>
> [image]

The primary colors in that beanie is another reason I thought “beanie” when I saw the image in your question.

The answer goes on to say:

> A Skull cap refers to certain types of headgear, usually tight to the skull, which can include:
>
> - Beanie (seamed cap), a brimless cap popular among school age boys
>     from the 1920s to the early 1940s
> - Gua pi mao (瓜皮帽), a hat commonly
>     worn in the Qing dynasty
> - A Kippah or yarmulke, is a small cloth
>     skullcap usually worn by Jewish men of most denominations while at
>     prayer, some Jewish women at prayer, and Orthodoxmen at all times.
> - Kufi, or kofia, a skullcap worn primarily by men of West African
>     heritage
> - Taqiyah (cap), a skullcap worn by some Muslim men
> - Tubeteika, a Central Asian cap
> - Tuque, a knit hat Zucchetto, worn by Catholic
>     clergy (including the Pope)
> - Biretta, a square or triangular black cap,
>     forming part of some clerical, academic or legal dress
> - Jeep cap, originating with the US Army, and popular among some skateboarders
> - Calotte (Belgium)"
>
> So, a **skull cap** is a tight fitting hat knitted, crocheted or made from woven material, usually brimless.

I can’t speak to the accuracy of every one of those hats, but I think the Quora answer does a good job of showing how complicated a taxonomy of hats can be. But it looks like *beanie* and *skull cap* might work for that hat in the picture.

Comment: Seamed caps (with a peak) were still being worn by British schoolboys in my childhood in the 1950s, and I suspect they go back to well before the 1920s. Some sportsmen wore them too. They're never called 'beanies' here, though!